# Removing all ASCII characters from Text File

Tags: java, ascii

I am doing research on a language called Malyalam and I am trying to make a word frequency chart with the most common words. However, the file I have has special characters in it along with the alphabet. I just want to delete these out of the text file. However I am having a lot of trouble with this. I am very new to programming and I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;     
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;          
import java.io.Reader;

public class Delete {

    public static void replaceInFile(File file) throws IOException {

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

        Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while(br.ready()) {
            fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("<", ""));
        }

        fw.close();
        br.close();
        fr.close();

        tempFile.renameTo(file);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

    {
        File jyothis = null;
        replaceInFile(jyothis);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure.  Just post the code you have attempted so far, and point out the spot that you are currently having trouble with.

Comment: So it isn't a text file.

Comment: The problem I'm having is being able to delete all the Ascii Characters at once and how to reference my text file

Comment: Question: why are you deleting "<" from your input file?  What significance does that character hold?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to delete all characters that are not _letters_? Many letters are also ASCII characters.

Comment: No I want to delete all character that ARE letters. The text file contains a language that looks like this ബതീവ. However it contains Latin letters and special characters that I wish to delete. And I was just testing my program so that's why I was using "<".

Comment: Besides "letters" (I assume you mean ASCII letters), what special characters do you want to delete?  It's important to have an exact definition what you want to do if we're to help you.  What about numbers?  Punctuation?  Control characters?

Comment: all the special characters. As in %^$#^124, etc. I just want the language left.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find sequences of characters from the [`MALAYALAM` Script](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html#MALAYALAM), you can use the regex [`\p{IsMalayalam}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode).

You could also choose the look for characters in the [`MALAYALAM` Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#MALAYALAM), using regex [`\p{InMalayalam}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode). Not sure if there really is a difference.

To eliminate all non-Malayalam characters, you'd want to retain spaces, to keep the sequences of Malayalam characters separated. If Malayalam characters are separated by only non-Malayalam characters other that spaces, you'd likely want to replace them with a space.

For better performance, you don't want to use `String.replaceAll()` inside a loop, so you'd do it like this:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile)));
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsMalayalam}+");
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        buf.setLength(0);
        for (Matcher m = p.matcher(line); m.find(); ) {
            if (buf.length() != 0)
                buf.append(' ');
            buf.append(m.group());
        }
        if (buf.length() != 0)
            out.println(buf);
    }
}
```

For a simpler implementation, you could do this (notice the use of uppercase `P` in the regex):

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile)));
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\P{IsMalayalam}+");
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; )
        out.println(p.matcher(line).replaceAll(" ").trim());
}
```

Comment: how would I reference my text file in the program? I am using the program eclipse

Comment: Just a warning. This assumes that the file is correctly read by FileReader (default local platform encoding).

Comment: @Zach What do you mean "reference my text file"? This code is "referencing" your files exactly like your code was doing it. This is a fragment of your code. You would of course still do the rename or whatever you wanted to, with the resulting file.

Comment: How do I use this program on my code is what i meant. Like how do I execute this program on the file I want

Comment: @Zach, replace the current implementation of `replaceInFile` with the version in this answer and in your `main` method, just call `replaceInFile(new File("/path/to/my/file"));`